# Center of mass of planar lamina

Tags: mass, geometry

Suppose that $D$ is a closed region in $\mathbb R^2$ and let $\rho$ be a density function on $D$. Then, is it possible that the center of mass lies on the boundary of $D$?

My intuition tells me that for any density $\rho$, it seems very improbable to balance the lamina at the boundary point, but is it really true?

Comment: It's not clear (to me) what your definition of D implies.  Does it exclude, say, a washer cut in half?

Comment: @User58220 It has no holes

Comment: neither does a washer cut in half... Think a thick letter "C"

Answer (score 1):

It does seem unlikely. Any non-zero mass density in the region inside the boundary will shift the center of mass away from the boundary, so my guess is no.